# Pyramid: how to get id of just created db row?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

In views:

```
model = Model('some_title', 'some text')
session.add(model)

return HTTPFound(location='/ads/%s/%s' % (model.id, model.title))
```

So, it must redirects me to `/ads/1/some_title` (if id=1), instead it redirects me to `/ads/None/some_title`.

How to get an `id` of this row after created db row in this particular example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

at the point you ask for `model.id`, the new model has not yet reached the database;  pyramid waits until the request handler returns before commiting the pending transaction.  To get the id earlier, you must flush the session.  Add:

```
model = Model('some_title', 'some text')
session.add(model)

session.flush()
return HTTPFound(location='/ads/%s/%s' % (model.id, model.title))
```